# What is the purpose of scope="prototype" in spring?

Tags: java, spring

From what I understand, if scope="prototype" is given for a bean, a new instance of that class is created on every request. So why would anyone use spring to create a new object instead of simply writing

```
ClassName newBean = new ClassName();
```

I have only used spring to create singletons.

Comment: because you can't get classes injected if you construct it yourself unless you call several setters. Also it allows the class to benefit from other spring features like AOP, which in turn allows easy transaction management, caching, asynchronous work etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you might want to inject other beans in your prototype. Or you might want to apply AOP aspects to methods of this bean. Or you might want to make it transactional. Or secure.

If you simply invoke the constructor of the class, it's not a Spring-managed bean anymore, and everything Spring does with beans is not done to the manually constructed object.

Answer (score 2):

One case I know of is when spring is used as an ObjectFactory for struts2. To create a new Action object for each http request.

Answer (score 0):

CMOE = "Close for Modification, Open for Extension."

If there is any behavior change for ClassName, then you can extend ClassName and provide the object of new class in config.

This will not require any code change.

This is one of simple reason. What JB Nizet said is more descriptive and in-depth ans.